# How do i sum rows of two tables and then subtract both in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a SUM of two different tables and then subtract both SUM both have Item and Quantity.

This are the tables:

[image: tables]

and then subtract each sum that should give SUM(t1) = 6264 and SUM(t2) = 3870 which gives 2394
The problem is when i do a left join on both tables i get

[image: this] result because of the left join

[image: left join].

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your question makes no sense without the query.  It is also better to include data samples as *text* tables rather than images.

Comment: Can’t  tell without the query joins, but you have sloppy joins that are to an extent multiplying the 13 on the left by the 5 on the right.  You will need to use a derived table or cte to group on column one in both tables and then left join t2 onto t1.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. But basically i need to join the tables After the SUM

Answer (score 0):

Using CTEs on limited join information in question, you can resolve the sums of two tables then join them together to get the net quantity:

```
with 
t1 (Attribute
    ,Quantity
,as (
    select
    t1.Attribute
    ,sum(Quantity) as Quantity)
    from dbo.t1
    )
,t2(
    Attribute
    ,Quantity
,as (
    select
    t2.Attribute
    ,sum(Quantity) as Quantity)
    from dbo.t2
    )
select
t1.Attribute
,isnull(t1.Quantity - t2.Quantity,t1.Quantity) AS NetQuantity
from t1
left join t2
    on t1.Attribute = t2.Attribute;
```